# How to specify IF condition to annotate with timestamp datatype in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, syntax

I use the syntax in sql like this

`` SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(updated_at,created_at) as 'timediff', IF(created_at > '07:00:00',"Late","On Time") as 'description' FROM `attendances`; ``

[image: SQL Image]

The result I want is if the time is more than 7 o'clock, then the result is late, if not, the result is on time, where is the syntax error in my sql?

Comment: created_at is a datetime, you want to compare `TIME(created_at)` to "07:00:00";

Comment: I do not know what your database is? SQL Server and MySql use CASE WHEN syntax instead of IF in the select statement. IF use in begin statement not in the DML